# Tag synonyms for British English/American English?

Tags: discussion, tags

As I did some tag wiki edits, I noticed a trend of having the American English spelling as the main tag, and sometimes there isn't a synonym created for it with the British English spelling. I was wondering if we do create tag synonyms for British English (although maybe this site may be from America)?

If that is a case, I thought of one that can use such a synonym:

[localisation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localisation) as a synonym of [localization](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization).

Comment: I don't think we'll need them, unless there are such overlapping tags

Comment: IMHO it is usually better to use existing tag (if it fits the subject) than to create a new one and it would be a very bad idea to introduce a new tag just because the one already introduced is not spelled the way you prefer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be done re-actively, not pro-actively. If at all.

[Tags use US English spelling by default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us/23873#23873).

If it gets to the point where there are plenty of users tagging with Proper English (UK) or some other non-US version, then a tag may be helpful.

Until then there would be no need to set it up as most spelling differences occur on the second half of the word itself.

An example would be, typing out "local..." and the system will show you the only "localisation" tag there in its US spelling and the one to use for the post. So it's unlikely a user, when shown this, wouldn't just use that tag that is only different a letter or two in spelling alone.

Comment: Ah great, now I understand it much better, thanks!

Comment: I spend most of my time on EL&U SE. We have tags for `American English`, `British English` and at least one other, probably two. But that pertains to the content of the question, not the spelling of a tag. I really appreciate that link to Meta SO, as I never know about that!

Comment: I just found this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48958/whats-the-deal-with-retagging-from-uk-english-to-us-english on MSO. In the answers, the English variety of tag usage IS explicitly discussed. It is consistent with your answer here.